# Check if object is within a cell range

Tags: excel, vba

I am building na interactive calculation in excel. The user will move the image and press a calculate button. If the image is within a certain cell range, then range ("c2") should identify which range the object is in (There are only 4 areas, they are year quarter squares, Q1,Q2,Q3 AND Q4. Q1 is within e1:j14)[image]

I have already been able to move the object via VBA, but I can´t check which range it is in:

```
ActiveSheet.Shapes("Grupo 24").Top = ActiveSheet.Range("B5").Offset(0, 4).Top
ActiveSheet.Shapes("Grupo 24").Left = ActiveSheet.Range("B5").Offset(3, 4).Left
```

The VBA above will move the object to a position (image above) just right of cell ("E5"), but I cannot do a check if the image is within ("E1:J14").

When I try to check, as a test, I get the error message: Error 13 incompatible types:

```
If ActiveSheet.Shapes("Grupo 24").Top = ActiveSheet.Range("e1:j14") Then
 MsgBox ("Within")
 Else
 MsgBox ("Outside")

 End If
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Hi! First things first.You are comparing a number with a `range` object. This is bound to give you an error. You can start by comparing similar things.  `Shapes("Grupo 24").Top` with `ActiveSheet.Range("e1:j14").top` for example. If you are not sure about what each property or method returns, always use `debug.print` to get an idea.

Comment: You are right, that was the the beggining! Didn´t answer, but error disappeared, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let us assume that we have already assigned the `Names` *quad1*, *quad2*, *quad3*, and *quad4* to the blocks of cells:

[image]

We determine which cell is associated with the `Shape` and then loop over the blocks to find which block the cell is in:

```
Sub quadFinder()
    Dim s As Shape, r As Range, i As Long

    Set s = ActiveSheet.Shapes("Grupo 24")
    Set r = s.TopLeftCell

    For i = 1 To 4
        If Not Intersect(r, Range("quad" & i)) Is Nothing Then
            MsgBox quad & i
            Exit Sub
        End If
    Next i

    MsgBox "not in a quad"
End Sub
```

Comment: Might have to check `BottomRight` as well because potentially top of the image could be in the `Quad` but not the bottom. Not sure if OP would class that as **out or range**

Comment: @Zac  **You are correct.** If the shape was very large and very poorly placed, it could overlap all 4 quads!

Answer (score 1):

Below you can see an example of what you could do:

```
Dim horizontalAxis As Boolean
Dim verticalAxis As Boolean
Dim sht As Worksheet
Dim testRng As Range

Set sht = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet3")
Set testRng = sht.Range("N1:S22")

horizontalAxis = sht.Shapes("Rectangle 1").Left >= testRng.Left And sht.Shapes("Rectangle 1").Left + sht.Shapes("Rectangle 1").Width <= testRng.Left + testRng.Width
Debug.Print horizontalAxis
verticalAxis = sht.Shapes("Rectangle 1").Top + sht.Shapes("Rectangle 1").Height <= testRng.Height
Debug.Print verticalAxis 
Debug.Print horizontalAxis And verticalAxis
```

For demonstration purposes, I am using a rectangle and a random range.

The code above checks if the shape is **strictly** inside the range. The smallest overlapping with a neighboring range will return false.